# Building a SQL "toxi" tagging system, how to select items with a specific tag?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

First of all, i'm new to sql.

Now, I'm building a tagging system with sqlite for my android app that uses 3 tables (items, tags, tagmap) based on this "toxi" solution found [here](http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas), but I'm not sure on how the mechanics work, how would I select all items from this itemsTable that have a specific tag.

**itemsTable**

itemid

2

3

4

**tagsTable**

tagid tag

2 "ruby"

3 "java"

7 "c"

**tagmap**

itemid tagid

2 3

3 7

2 2

4 7

I was trying something along the lines of:

`SELECT* FROM itemsTable INNER JOIN tagmap ON tagmap.itemid= itemsTable.itemid AND tagmap.tagid=tagsTable.tagid WHERE tagsTable.tagid= desiredid`

But this seems to be wrong.

BTW: all itemid and tagsid are primary keys auto-incremented

Any answers or an alternative to creating a tagging system(in which an item can have more than one tag) are welcomed.

Comment: Your query looks okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong. You did not include the "tagsTable" in your join. Try this:

```
SELECT* FROM itemsTable INNER JOIN tagmap ON tagmap.itemid= itemsTab 
INNER JOIN tagsTable ON tagmap.tagid=tagsTable.tagid WHERE tagsTable.tagid= desiredID
```